# Separate/grid from columns and inside column rows using flex, and align image in one column in the center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm moving from floats to flexbox I have some issues.

I have the following code:

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid green;
   margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.card .image {
 border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
 padding: 1.2rem;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.card .body {
 padding: 1.2rem;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.card .logo {
 margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

title {  padding:  0 0 0.8rem 0;}
text { padding: 0}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="image"><img src="../img/product_image_sample1.png" width="120"></div>
    <div class="body">
        <img src="logo_sample.png" width="120"/>
        <a href=# class="title">KIT</a>
        <span class="text"> tae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum</span>
</div>
</div>
```

I want the `.image` to be vertical align in the middle, and to have padding bottom between `logo, title and text`;

I need to work with IE10, IE11 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1: Flexbox can not implemented on I.E 11 and below so you would have to use floats as a fallback. (If this is workeable for you add a comment below or ask a new question)

On centering check the css I edited. Add flexbox to item and use `align-items:center` to make it centered vertically.

In your markup you forgot to add the class for logo. That's why it doesn't work.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid green;
   margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.card .image {
 border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
 padding: 1.2rem;
  /*Make the item a flexbox item and center the item vertically*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.card .body {
 padding: 1.2rem;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.card .logo {
 padding: 0 0 0.8rem 0;
}

title {  padding:  0 0 0.8rem 0;}
text { padding: 0}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492257027549-2617847dc868?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=494b1d11506d9e6babb320454e8a5798" width="120"></div>
    <div class="body">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492257027549-2617847dc868?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=494b1d11506d9e6babb320454e8a5798" width="120" class="logo" />
        <a href=# class="title">KIT</a>
        <span class="text"> tae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
    justify-content: center
    align-items: center
   }
```

Also I found these videos very helpful

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siKKg8Y_tQY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdlEEfx912M